# Unable to download file in laravel using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

When I am trying to use the download button to download file in laravel, it is not working properly and I am not able to download file. there is code.

info.blade.php

```
    @if ($user->is_maba)
    <x-button id="coCard" :tagA="true" class="bg-base-blue-300 hover:bg-base-blue-400 uppercase text-md whitespace-nowrap my-3"
        target="_blank" href="{{ route('home.cocard', ['id' => $user->id])}}">
        Download Co Card
    </x-button>
    @endif
```

coCard.blade.php

```
<x-home-layout menu="CoCard" title="CoCard">

    <div class="font-poppins lg:px-40 md:px-30 sm:px-16 px-3 lg:pt-32 md:pt-28 pt-24 mb-20">

        <div class="grid justify-items-center">
            <div class="text-base-blue-400 mb-5 text-center">
                <h1 class="font-extrabold xl:text-4xl lg:text-3xl md:text-2xl sm:text-xl text-xl leading-normal">
                    Menyiapkan Co Card ...
                </h1>
                <p class="text-base mt-4 italic">Harap tunggu sebentar ...</p>
                <div id="qrcode" class="hidden"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="xl:w-45 lg:w-32 md:w-24 sm:w-20 w-16 h-2 bg-base-yellow-400"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @push('script-bottom')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js')}}" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/qrcode.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const getQRCode = () =>{
            new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
                text: "{{ $username }}",
            });
        };
        getQRCode();
    </script>
    <script>
        let url;
        var generateUrlQrCode = async() => {
            let qrcode = document.getElementById("qrcode").firstElementChild;
            let blob = await new Promise(resolve=>qrcode.toBlob(resolve));
            url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        };

        generateUrlQrCode();
        
        const getCoCard = () => {
            const doc = new jspdf('l', 'cm', 'a4', true);
            const width = 18;
            const height = 13;

            doc.addImage(`<?= $imgDepan ?>`, "PNG", 0, 0, width, height, '','FAST');
            doc.addImage(`<?= $desainDepan ?>`, "PNG", 0, 0, width, height, '','FAST');
            doc.addImage(`${url}`, "PNG", 6.5, 4.33, 5, 5, '','FAST');
            doc.addPage('l', 'cm', 'a4', true);
            doc.addImage(`<?= $imgBelakang ?>`, "PNG", 0, 0, width, height, '','FAST');
            doc.addImage(`<?= $desainBelakang ?>`, "PNG", 0, 0, width, height, '','FAST');
            doc.save(`<?= $nimb; ?>` + "_CoCard.pdf");

            setTimeout(() => {
                window.close();
            }, 1000);
        }

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            setTimeout(getCoCard, 500);
        });
    </script>
    @endpush
</x-home-layout>
```

is there something missing in my code? beacuse when i click, there is no file download are coming in

Comment: Well, there are 2 things to keep an eye on after the click. They're both in the chrome devtools. 1) Console: any errors? Copy/paste the errors. 2) Network tab. Click on the red line if there is any. Click on "response". Copy/paste the response (usually preview has nice layout)

Comment: So `doc.save(\`<?= $nimb; ?>\` + "_CoCard.pdf");` should download the file?  You are not actually using laravel to download anything, only to populate `imgDepan, imgBelakang` etc  as far as I can see. You are using jspdf and do not even need a separate blade for that

Comment: PS: `doc.save("<?= $nimb; ?>_CoCard.pdf")` is cleaner